# VB.net Messages Pumped to Label

Tags: vb.net, message

I basically want to implement a Label and have it constantly showing information to the user. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
someMethod():
    printMessage("Starting program")
    doWork() //possibly does some calls to printMessage()
    printMessage("Finished program")
end

printMessage(string message)
    mylabel.Text += message
end
```

And have the label on a Windows Form constantly be showing that output. That is, instead of the user having to wait until someMethod() is finished and having all the info suddenly dumped on to the label, I want it to be printed to the label as the information comes out.

I tried looking at threading to solve this problem, and I have it working using code something like:

```
someMethod():
    Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf printMessage)
    t.Start("Starting program")
    doWork()
    printMessage("Finished program")
end
```

(And there is a delegate for printMessage and inside I check the InvokedRequired property of mylabel) But with this, I keep getting all the information just suddenly dumped on to the label, and the order is no longer preserved. I may get output like:

```
"some other data from doWork()"
"Finished program"
"Starting program"
```

So any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using a `BackgroundWorker`.  It will make it easy for you to have the work done on a separate thread and still report progress back to the UI thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

And have the rest of the app remain responsive.

The BackGroundWorker has a DoWork event where you could put code that looked (roughly) like this:

```
BGW.ReportProgress(0, "Starting Task1")
DoTask1()
BGW.ReportProgress(0, "Completed Task1")

BGW.ReportProgress(0, "Starting Task2")
DoTask2()
BGW.ReportProgress(0, "Completed Task2")
```

You'd also handle the ProgressChanged event which will fire (on the thread that started the worker) to update the label.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link and information, Rob. I'll try implementing that tomorrow and let you know if it solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: I tried this out today and it worked great. Thanks a lot Rob! It did require a bit of refactoring on my part to make it work as intended, but it works great now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A call to `Application.DoEvents()` may be beneficial, as it forces the window to update.

Try placing it right after each of your `printMessage` calls.

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but Application.DoEvents() has some negative side effects and should be avoided

Comment: Okay, what are those side effects?

Comment: It's called "function reentry", where the current execution of the function is waiting for the DoEvents() call, and one of the events to be processed results in the same method running while it's still waiting.  In some cases this can lead to a stack overflow because the function will keep getting called (ie, if your function is called by an event handler for something frequent like OnMouseMove). In others it can result in broken program state, especially if you use static members from your method (and even if you think you don't use static members, this is a common compiler optimization)

Comment: Okay, well even if it has those side effects, I still don't see why there are now two downvotes. My answer does as OP requested.

Comment: Well thanks a lot for taking the time to read my question and respond, Cyclone. I learned something here, and part of that thanks goes to you too, Joel. Thank you both for the information.